# Can we put dictionary items(array) into a Range with a single statement?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Suppose i do have an array A1(6)=(45,25,,36,88),A2(6)=(14,25,11),A3(6)=(11,21,20,25,48).Now can we put those array values with the help of a single statement like single array assignment to a row,as here all the rows to a range of an Excel, Say here "C1:R3" range.

```
Dim R
R = Split(Join(A1, ",") & "," & Join(A2, ",") & "," & Join(A3, ","), ",")
Range("C5:T5").Value = R
```

Now can we do dictionary Items(which is an array) combine into a 1D array and assign back to a Range?

```
For Each ChilID In ChildIDs

    Redim ChildDetailArray(ArrIndex)
    ChildMatchNum=objExcel1.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ChilID, ob3.Columns(1), 0)
    ChildDetailArray=ob1.Range(ob1.Cells(ChildMatchNum,1),ob1.Cells(ChildMatchNum,ArrIndex+1)).Value
    ChildDic.Add ChilID,ChildDetailArray '(ChildDetailArray is an array)

Next
```

**EDIT1**

```
      suppose a process#20 has 2 child processes say #12,#13. now i used a dictionary object Dic

        Dic(12)=Arr(10,11,,,18) 'child details
        Dic(13)=Arr(5,8,9,,,) ' child details

    ***Output:***  `1D array say ArrMerger()=(10,11,,,18,5,8,9,,,)`
```

The above `For Loop` is doing the same.now when the `Loop` will be finished,i want those child details which are the item of Dic(12) and Dic(13) needs to be collected in an 1D array

***UPDATE***

```
      strJoin = ","
For ChildKey In ChildDic.Keys

    strJoin=Join(ChildDic(ChildKey),",") & strJoin

Next
```

Thanks

Comment: @Tukai I do not see a *`Dictionary`* here... But I have provided you an answer to your question as per the title. As long as you do have data in a `Dictionary`, you can take those items into a `1D variant array`. So you may `Transpose` it into the desired `Range.` On a *duplicate note*, this is the same question as what you discussed yesterday?

Comment: @bonCodigo please see me `EDIT`

Comment: So you want to `merge two 1D array items from Dictionary into a 1D array`?

Comment: @bonCodigo Yes,Sir! you catched me now perfectly!!

Comment: @bonCodigo please see me **EDIT**

Comment: @Tukai, do take a look at the editted output. And comment please if that's what you need :) we are there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21593/discussion-between-vbslover-and-boncodigo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Can we put dictionary items(array) into a Range with a single statement??* **YES, You can get all dictionary items into a range.**

Try this code and explain ***clearly*** / comment any changes you require:

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub getMerged1DItems()
Dim d As Object, d2 As Object
Dim vArr As Variant
Dim vArr2 As Variant
Dim strJoin As String

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set d2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    '-- assume you have items in your dictionary
    d.Add "Names", 1
    d.Add "Titles", 2
    d.Add "Jobs", 3
    d.Add "Education", 4
    d.Add "Experience", 5

    '-- add dictionary items into an 1D array
    vArr = d.Keys

    '-- add 1D arryas into d2 dictionary as items
    d2("v" & 1) = vArr
    d2("v" & 2) = vArr

    '-- join multiple 1D array items into one string delimitted by comma
    strJoin = Join(d2("v" & 1), ", ") & "," & Join(d2("v" & 2), ", ")

    '-- split the string by comma delimiter
    vArr2 = Split(strJoin, ",")

    '-- output to sheet using first 1D Array
    Sheets(1).Range("B2").Resize(1, _
             UBound(Application.Transpose(vArr))) = vArr

    '-- output to sheet using dictionary
    Sheets(1).Range("B4").Resize(1, _
             UBound(Application.Transpose(d.Keys))) = d.Keys

    'output to sheet using mergeed 1D array
    Sheets(1).Range("B7").Resize(1, _
             UBound(Application.Transpose(vArr2))) = vArr2

    Set d2 = Nothing
    Set d = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: that's perfect,but i asked something different.

Comment: output looks good as expected but which statement did such merger? I think it is not there,I am actually looking for an way by which all the arrays' are to be merged first with its proper size,then doing transport() on them would paste them to Excel!

Comment: @Tukai, the comment `'--join multiple 1D arrays into 1 string...` merged the arrays. Then `split` function put it into one final 1D `array`. You have nothing to worry about sizes here. It's all dynamic. Only thing, probably you need to do is run a `for loop to add all 1D arrays into a dictionary`. Then loop dictionary to get each item (1D Array) for the join statement. **I REALLY HOPE THIS JOINED STRING WILL NOT EXCEED THE CHARACTER LIMIT....AS WELL AS SHEET COLUMNS LIMIT...**

Comment: Yes! your catch is perfect! I am wondering at run time means when the `for loop` will be ended then how should I form the merge statement you provided! as i am using child ID as the Dic key and chld details as an array to the item of each key. Inside the `loop` how would I?

Comment: Can you show us your `Child` structure. It's difficult to comment when you do not show the declarations of these objects you use.................

Comment: @Tukai if things are solved by the answer can you wrap this up by marking the answer? Else let us know if you have further doubts.

Comment: I usually never downvote people here :) even the question is super not acceptable... I will look at one of your really good questions :) BTW I am curious to know what exact structure you want to implement. If you could show `child` object structure, it would make things much clearer.

Comment: There is an excel sheet which has process id details. and all the child and parent id has same column structure. Now one of my script will define that relationship. after that another script use those relation ship and create each record to another sheet for each parent and then if that parent has any child in that same row all the child details would be merged up,thus i was looking for a quick merger process.

Comment: please see my update, and tell if my construction is wrong or right? please see!

Comment: "With a single statement" is missing in the solution